# Visual C++ 2010 Express - No C/C++ Folder showing up in Project Property Pages

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm trying to set an Additional Include Directory in a Visual, which I understand usually exists in a 'C/C++' folder. When I go to a DLL project's folder, though, I don't see any C/C++ folders. I only see 'VC++ Directories' and 'Linker'.

The funny thing is that I am able to see that 'C/C++' folder on my work laptop ... just not on my home PC. Any ideas how I get the 'C/C++' folder to show up so that I can set Additional Include Directories?

Comment: Sorry - I completely misread your question and posted a non answer. I don't know why the C/C++ entry is missing. Have you tried repairing or reinstalling Visual Studio? Is this happening on all projects or just a few? Are you running as an Admin on your home PC?

Comment: All projects. I've uninstalled VS using both the Control Panel "Uninstall" as well as the VS Uninstall tool from MSDN. Reinstalls didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create at least one C++ file (.cpp) for the C/C++ item to show up in the project properties.